# laravel:database employee id and name as qrcode

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

laravel generate qrcode using employee list using their id

here's my route

```
Route::get('/employee/printqr/{empcode?}/{empname?}', 'EmployeeController@printQr');
```

in view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<img src="{{ Storage::url("emp_qr_codes/") }}{{ $empcode }}.png" style="width: 250px;"/>
<br/>
Employee Code: {{ $empcode }}
<br/>
Employee Name: {{ $empname }}
<script>
    var empcode = @json($empcode);
    var empname = @json($empname);
    var ttt = '<br><br>' +
        '<img src="{{ Storage::url("emp_qr_codes/") }}' + empcode + '.png" style="width:250px;" />' +
        '<br>Employee Code: ' + empcode +
        '<br>Employee Name: ' + empname;
    var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
    newWin.document.open();
    newWin.document.write('<html><body>' + ttt + '</body></html>');
    newWin.document.close();
    newWin.focus();
    setTimeout(function () {
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }, 150);
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = '/employee/index';
    }, 160);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here's my controller

```
public function getAllEmployeesList()
    {
        $list = array();
        $list['data'] = array();
        $qry = Employee::where('emp_active_status', 'Y')->where("emp_role_id", 6)->get()->toArray();
        $list['iTotalRecords'] = count($qry);
        $list['iTotalDisplayRecords'] = count($qry);
        foreach ($qry as $emp) {
            $emp['name'] = $emp['emp_first_name'] . ' ' . $emp['emp_last_name'];
            $emp['emp_date_of_join'] = date('d/M/Y', strtotime($emp['emp_date_of_join']));

            $list['data'][] = $emp;
        }
        return json_encode($list);
```

and i cannot generate all the employee id as qr code with qrcode code piker using id

this is my printq function:

```
public function printQr($empcode, $empname)
    {
        return view('employee/print', compact('empcode', 'empname'));
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please elaborate with code snippets

Comment: please look at these and i changed something

Comment: I mentioned a few improvements, Please share your "printQr" function so I can see your logic

Comment: look at printqr function @MuhammadFaranAli

Comment: Update answer with few suggestion, See if that works for you

Comment: it doesn't  work @MuhammadFaranAli

Comment: where did you get error ?

Comment: on function and view

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAllEmployeesList()
{
    $response = collect()

     //get All employees
    $employees = Employee::where('emp_active_status', 'Y')->where("emp_role_id", 6)->get();

    // put all employees in response collection against employees key
    $response->put('employees', $employees);

    // put all employees count in response collection against iTotalRecords key
    $response->put('iTotalRecords', $employees->count())

    // put all employees count in response collection against iTotalDisplayRecords key
    $response->put('iTotalDisplayRecords', $employees->count()) //this doesn't make sense

    return json_encode($list);
}
```

And add these in model

```
    // this will join first name and last name
    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return ($this->emp_first_name . ' ' . $this->emp_last_name);
    }

    // This will format your dates automatically

    protected $casts = [
       'emp_date_of_join'  => 'date:Y-m-d'
    ];

    //Your route should be
    Route::get('/employee/printqr/{empcode}/{empname}', 'EmployeeController@printQr');

    // install this package
    composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode


   // config/app.php
   'providers' => [
      SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\QrCodeServiceProvider::class
    ],

   'aliases' => [
     'QrCode' => SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode::class
    ],

    //in view if you want to list all employees qrcode
    @foreach ($employees as $employee)
      <p>{!! QrCode::size(200)->generate($employee->empcode. '-'.$request->empname); !!}</p>
    @endforeach

    //if you want to generate code against empcode being send in request url
    <p>{!! QrCode::size(200)->generate($request->empcode. '-'.$request->empname); !!}</p>
```